# JPA update query with condition on nested object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have entity:

```
public class Child {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName="ID", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Person parent;
private Integer age;

}
```

Person is another entity ofcourse. It just has id and age for simplicity.

And the query that does not work:

```
@Query("update Child c set c.age = 10 where c.parent.id = :parentId)
void updateChild(@Param("parentId) parentId)
```

I think it is related to nested c.parent.id property because when I use other properties, not nested ones it updates fine. How to update such child ? Is it possible to put nested path in where clause like I did, should it work ?

> The exception is SQL Error: 156, SQLState: S0001  Falsche Syntax in
> der Nahe des cross-Schlusserlworts.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong the problem is not in nested object but in syntax of `UPDATE` query, the error that you get tells you about it.

```
SQL Error: 156, SQLState: S0001
```

You are missing `SET` part of update

`SET` is absolutely mandatory in the `UPDATE` statement!

You have to update the query according to syntax

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

**UPDATE**

After analyze of the query I could say that the method should look like:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("update Child c set c.age = 10 where c.parent.id = :parentId")
void updateChild(@Param("parentId") Long parentId);
```

Comment: I have set in clause, I corrected it, unfortunatelly I made mistake writing post here. So set clause is there.. I updated my post.

Comment: Have you tried to add `@Modifying` annotation on the repository method ?

Comment: The exception is with @Modyfying annotation. Without this annotation I get: 
Not supported for DML operations [update mypackage.Child c set c.age = 10 where c.parent.id = :parentId]

Comment: Leave it with modifying annotation and also add `@Transactional` annotation on the query

Comment: The same happens even after adding @Transactional, I give up for today ;)

Comment: Let me try this code and I will come back with an update of the answer

Comment: If it also still not work show me as update of the question usage of update method.